# Using Bytebuddy to intercept setter

Tags: java, byte-buddy

lets asume i have a Interface like that:

```
public interface User extends Element {

    String getName();

    String getPassword();

}
```

and a implementing class like that:

```
public class BaseUser implements User {

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Set name to " + name);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

}
```

Now i want to use bytebuddy to create a interceptor/proxy which catches the call onto the setter, store the changed value and call the real method also.

At the end i want to "ask" the interceptor/proxy for the called setter and the changed values.

I tried a lot considering also the tutorials but up to now i found no working solution. Maybe someone could help me pls.

And here is the Interceptor:

```
public class GenericInterceptor implements InvocationHandler {

    @Override
    @RuntimeType
    public Object invoke(@This Object proxy, @Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (isSetter(method, args)) {
            intercept(proxy, method, args);
        }
        return method.invoke(proxy, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my current 'test' code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ByteBuddy bb = new ByteBuddy();
    final GenericInterceptor interceptor = new GenericInterceptor();

    bb.subclass(BaseUser.class)
            .method(isDeclaredBy(BaseUser.class).and(isSetter()))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor))
            .make()
            .load(BaseUser.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER);

    final BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
    user.setName("my name");
}
```

EDIT:

```
public interface Element {
    String getId();
}

public class GenericInterceptor<T extends Element> {

    public GenericInterceptor(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getChanges(T obj) {
        final String id = obj.getId();
        return changes.get(id);
    }

    @RuntimeType
    public void invoke(@This T proxy, @Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("invoke " + method.getName() + " " + Arrays.toString(args));

        intercept(proxy, method, args);
    }

    private Object getCurrentValue(T proxy, final Field field) {
        try {
            return field.get(proxy);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Field getSetterField(Method setter) {
        final String setterName = setter.getName();

        Field f = assignedFields.get(setterName);
        if (f != null) return f;

        final String fieldName = Character.toLowerCase(setterName.charAt(3)) + setterName.substring(4);
        try {
            f = type.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            if (f == null) return null;
            f.setAccessible(true);
            assignedFields.put(setterName, f);
            return f;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void intercept(T proxy, Method setter, Object[] args) {
        final Field field = getSetterField(setter);
        if (field == null)
            return;

        final Object currentValue = getCurrentValue(proxy, field);
        final Object newValue = args[0];

        System.out.println("Set from " + currentValue + " to " + newValue);

        final String id = proxy.getId();
        Map<String, Object> changeMap = changes.get(id);
        if (changeMap == null) {
            changeMap = new HashMap<>();
        }
        changeMap.put(field.getName(), currentValue);
        changes.put(id, changeMap);
    }

    private final Map<String, Field> assignedFields = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Map<String, Object>> changes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private final Class<T> type;

}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to post the code You wrote to handle this.

Comment: added the current code i have, but the interceptor is not called yet

Comment: You never remove anything from the `changes` `Map`, hence creating a memory leak.

Comment: @k5 thats true, but its just experimental code so i don't care about that ... but thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call orignal method using *MethodDelegation.to(...).andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE)*.

```
public class ByteBuddyTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
      GenericInterceptor interceptor = new GenericInterceptor ();

      Class<?> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(BaseUser.class)
        .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(BaseUser.class).and(ElementMatchers.isSetter()))
            .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor))))
        .make()
        .load(ByteBuddyTest.class.getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();

      BaseUser user1 = (BaseUser) clazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
      BaseUser user2 = (BaseUser) clazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
      user1.setName("user1");
      user1.setPassword("password1");
      user2.setName("user2");
      user2.setPassword("password2");

      System.out.println(interceptor.getInterceptedValue("user1", "name"));
      System.out.println(interceptor.getInterceptedValue("user1", "password"));
      System.out.println(interceptor.getInterceptedValue("user2", "name"));
      System.out.println(interceptor.getInterceptedValue("user2", "password"));

      user1.setPassword("password2");
      user1.setPassword("password3");
  }

  public static class GenericInterceptor {
      private Map<String, Object> interceptedValuesMap = new HashMap();

      public void set(String obj, @This User user, @Origin Method setter) {
        // assume that user name is unique so we can use it as a key in values map.
        // or define equals/hashcode in GenericUser object and use it as a key directly
        String setterName = setter.getName();
        String propertyName = setterName.substring(3, setterName.length()).toLowerCase();
        String key = user.getName() + "_" + propertyName;

        System.out.println("Setting " + propertyName + " to " + obj);
        System.out.println("Previous value " + interceptedValuesMap.get(key));

        interceptedValuesMap.put(key, obj);
      }

    public Object getInterceptedValue(String userName, String fieldName) {
        return interceptedValuesMap.get(userName + "_" + fieldName);
    }
  }

  public static interface User {

      String getName();

      String getPassword();

  }

  public static class BaseUser implements User {

      @Override
      public String getName() {
          return name;
      }

      @Override
      public String getPassword() {
          return password;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }

      public void setPassword(String password) {
          this.password = password;
      }

      private String name;
      private String password;

  }
}
```

Comment: okay thank you for the fast answer .. works for me fine but one more thing :-) the interceptor currently only catches the set value. but i also want to get the current value stored in the users field. currently i hand over the BaseUser to the GenericInterceptor and search for the field by reflection
could bytebuddy inject this for me to the interceptor? This does create a endless recursion when calling it and SuperCall offers only the possibility to call the setter and not the getter or the field

Comment: Not sure i get what You mean. In the interceptor we store the value that is then set on the intertcepted User object, so User object will have the same value as stored in the interceptor.

Comment: Do You need to store all set values per User class instance?

Comment: what i mean is, that i need a interceptor instance for every base user object. i bytebuddy could inject the base user instance like the method and the args i could have one single interceptor instance.

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe something similar will suite Your needs.

Comment: yes indeed :-) i also updated my current test implementation above. is it possible to intercept a existing object instead of creating a new one with "newInstance" ?

Comment: This could be done only if You apply ByteBuddy instrumentation before BaseUser class is loaded. Then You can rebase/redefine instead of subclassing and every created instance of BaseUser will be intercepted.

Comment: Can be solved with Java Agent if You can use it in your solution.

Comment: yes i read this at bytebuddy.net but java agent or anything else special is no option for me