# ByteBuddy - redefine all classes that are in a given pacakge

Tags: java, spring-boot, byte-buddy

I have a package called `com.company.beans`.
What I would like to do, is to `upperCase` and `trim` all fields of type `String` for each class from this package.
I've seen this post [Using Bytebuddy to intercept setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104098/using-bytebuddy-to-intercept-setter)
which seems to be a good solution to what I want to do.

Here is the piece of code I'm trying to redefine :

```
 bb.subclass(BaseUser.class) // how to specify my package ? 
            .method(isDeclaredBy(BaseUser.class).and(isSetter()))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor))
            .make()
            .load(BaseUser.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER);
```

How do I specify all classes from a given package ?
Also, I'm using spring boot. Where should I put my ByteBuddy configuration ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: StackOverflow is designed to answer one question per post, so future users can find the exact answer to their particular question. Here you have more than 1 question in the post. Please split your task into several subtasks and try to solve them one by one

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries to scan the class path such as [Class Graph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) which you can use for this purpose. There's nothing in Byte Buddy for it since this is considered a different domain.